# pygtk: determine key is a modifier

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, pygtk

I've got key-press-event handler and i need to determine which kind of key was pressed: modifier or not?

It's not in event.state, because this field works only when modifier was pressed with something else, but i need this for single key (i.e. simply pressing control or alt, ...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your version of GTK+/PyGTK is recent enough, key events have a `is_modifier` attribute. It's not documented in the PyGTK reference, but it's in the GDK API documentation and is exposed through PyGTK. It was added in GDK 2.10.

Answer (score 2):

You'll find what you're looking for in event.keyval. For example, the following code works for me:

```
def key_press_event(widget, event):
    keyname = gtk.gdk.keyval_name(event.keyval)
    if "Control" in keyname or "Alt" in keyname:
        print "You pressed a modifier!"
```

Comment: i've got something like what you've shown, but much bigger:

    MODIFIERS=(
            gtk.keysyms.Control_L,          
            .....
            gtk.keysyms.Hyper_L,            
            gtk.keysyms.Hyper_R,            
            gtk.keysyms.Meta_L,
            gtk.keysyms.Meta_R,
    )

    ....

    if event.keyval in MODIFIERS:
       ....

but i thought there could be some another approach